# Flutter Restore In App Purchase with 'in-app-purchase'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a 'restore purchases' feature for my app using 'in-app-purchase' package.

I'm using `InAppPurchase.restorePurchases()`, and I do see new purchases inside my stream with a status of `'restored'`, and I'm also sending the receipt to the app store for verification, but **I'm not sure whether or not items are restored**:

Once I restore the purchase, the receipt I get back from the app store looks identical to the one when the user made the purchase, and on top of that, when I attempt to make the purchase again, it says I can get it for **free** since I've purchased it before.. Is that normal?

Here's my code:

**Restore Purchases Function:**

```html
/// Restores all purchases
  Future<void> _restore(PurchasableProduct product) async {
    // the auth id that was linked to the original purchase
    final applicationUserName = authUser.uid;

    await iapConnection.restorePurchases(
      applicationUserName: applicationUserName,
    );
  }
```

**Handle purchases function:**

```html
Future<void> _handlePurchase(
    PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails,
  ) async {
      final purchaseStatus = purchaseDetails.status;
      final isPurchase = purchaseStatus == PurchaseStatus.purchased;
      final isRestore = purchaseStatus == PurchaseStatus.restored;
      
       if (isPurchase || isRestore) {
        // Send to server for verification
        var validPurchase = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
        
        if (validPurchase) {
          // grant/revoke rewards
        }
       }
       
       // mark purchase as complete
       if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await iapConnection.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
  }
```

**'in-app-purchase'** recognizing my restore request:
[image]

**Post request to apple:**

```html
  const body = {
      "receipt-data" : payload.receiptData,
      "password" : password,
      "exclude-old-transactions" : false,
  };
  
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };
  
const url = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions); // this returns the receipt in the image below
```

**Purchase Receipt AFTER it had been restored:**
[image]

**According to apple,** I should see the fields `cancellation_date`,`cancellation_reason` when a refund request is sent, which I don't see..

I'm doing everything according to the `in-app-purchase` documentation, looked everywhere on the internet, but I can't figure this out. I'd really appreciate any insight you might have!

Thanks!

Comment: hey, were you able to find solution for this?